# How to add scope_identity() to UNION ALL syntax in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query for multiple inserts using `UNION ALL`.

How do I use `SELECT scope_identity();` for each row of data inserted?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
   SELECT 'First', 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Second', 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Third', 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Fourth', 4
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Fifth', 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no you can't. SCOPE_IDENTITY will give you the value of the last insert only. But you can use the OUTPUT clause from 2005 onwards. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx for information on how to use this clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OUTPUT Clause to get Multiple Identity Column Value instead of scope_identity() while inserting Multiple Row.

```
Create Table tablename 
(id int identity(1,5) Primary KEY, b int , c int) 

DECLARE @tempIDs TABLE (id int)

INSERT tablename (b, c)
OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @tempIDs
   SELECT 1, 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 2, 2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 200, 3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 3000, 4
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 400, 5

Select * from @tempIDs
```

Now your table variable @tempIDs have All Primary Key Data those are inserted using UNION ALL.